# Excel macro - add one column to another

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a Excel worksheet with data like this:

```
VISIT  <48  >48  TOTAL BILLED   NOT BILLED

10      4   3         7             3
```

I need a macro that will add the *not-billed* to the *<48* i.e. 3+4= 7. 
7 would then replace the 4.

I tried `C13=C13+F13` but it does not compile.

Comment: That is a circular reference, and should be handled with vba not formulas.

Comment: That's a dangerous approach. How would you know by just looking at the data that the Not Billed has already been added to the <48 column if you overwrite the existing value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I wrote a tested and working **macro** as requested.
Assuming your Cell **columns** is the same as in the section below. (Note that the rows may differ and may start on different positions)

You can select the rows that needs to be processed as displayed in the picture.

[image]

```vb
    Sub calculate()
    ' Calculates for each row in any selection
    ' Takes value in C and add value in F if value in F is larger than 0 then afterwards makes value in f equal to 0
    ' Asumes that Column "C" have the "Visit" and Column "F" is the "Not Billed" columns

    Dim sel As Range
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim l As Long

        Set sel = Selection

        For Each rw In sel ' Adapt this to however you need to specify the selection you want to work with
            If (Cells(rw.Row, 6).Value > 0) Then ' Test if the value need to be processed
                l = Cells(rw.Row, 3).Value + Cells(rw.Row, 6).Value
                Cells(rw.Row, 6).Value = 0
                Cells(rw.Row, 3).Value = l
                'Cells(rw.Row, 3) would be column C
                'Cells(rw.Row, 6) would be column F
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
```

After running the macro your file will look like:

[image]

Let me know if it works for you.